# Is it possible to add a browser code in javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I would like to create a webpage with browser specific in javascript.

For example:

can I use code like this in my coding part

`chrome.tab.onRemoved.addListener()` in my webpage.

If it is possible please suggest me.

Comment: Can you tell what exactly are you trying to acheive?

Comment: i need to catch tab close or browser close event, to ask customer feedback before close.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What exactly are you tring to acheive?

If you want to know when the tab in which your webpage is loaded is closed, then [window.onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) should help you.

If you want to know when another webpage is closed, you cannot do this.

**UPDATE:**
You said that you want to know when the user closes the browser or tab. This is not possible.

But for your purpose (getting feedback), I think all you need is to differentiate whether the user is navigating to a link in your page, or whether the user is typing another URL(or by clicking a favorite).

I think for your requirement, whether the user closes the browser, or whether he types another URL, is the same - the user is navigating away from your site, and at that time you say you want to collect feedback.

This can be done in javascript.

> For all the clicks in your page that
>   might lead to a page refresh
>   (hyperlinks, buttons,...), set a flag.
>   In `window.onunload`, check whether
>   this flag is set.
>   - If it is set, then
>   the user has clicked a link in your
>   page, do nothing.
>   - If the flag is not
>   set then the user is navigating away,
>   time to collect feedback.

Let me know if this would work.

PS: Note that popups/any distractions during window.unload can be very annoying.
I understand that this probably is the requirements given to you. But if possible, try other mechanisms to collect (voluntary) feedback from the user.

Comment: I only need to know whether the user is closing the page or just navigating. In window.onunload and window.onbeforeunload, the events trigger for all navigation and also close event. I particularly need to find the browser or window close event.

Comment: I dont think it is possible to see whether the user is closing the window or not. But for your purpose, I think it is sufficient to see whether the user is navigating via some link in your page, or whether the user has typed another URL (or clicked on a bookmark) to navigate away from your page. Have updated the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: That was supposed to be 'voluntary' feedback, btw.

Comment: @Nivas : What will happen on a refresh ? User is not navigating away here. Flag is not set. Here will assume that it i s page browser/tab close.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot access extension-specific APIs from webpages.

Answer (score 2):

The Navigator object contains all information about the visitor's browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.navigator

I think this is pretty much the extent of what is possible in terms of interacting with the specific browser.  You can't access other tabs (for security reasons) or tell when a tab is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use the onbeforeunload event:

```
<html>  
  <head>
    <script>

    var exit = 1;

    function handleClose()
    {      
        if (exit)
        {
            alert("Closing");
        }
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onbeforeunload="handleClose()">
    <a href="test.html" onclick="exit=0">Navigate to other page</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's for the tab where the script is running, it doesn't tell you if another tab is closed...

Comment: You cannot find out if some other tab is closed, is not relevant to your site. You cannot do this because is will be a browser security breach.

Comment: The `onbeforeunload` is only for the WINDOW closed and not for the BROWSER closed.

Comment: Your browser will first close all tabs and then close itself. So WINDOW closed will be called before the browser.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload