# Logging DateTime in SQL Table When Users Session Ends

Tags: c#, sql, session, datetime

I have written an application and with this application the user has to login. I have a table where I am keeping their login token for that session, datetime they logged in, datetime they logged out and the duration in which they were logged in.

This functionality works great when the user actually goes and clicks `Logout`. If the user does not click `Logout`, then it will not take the datetime for the logout and it won't give me the duration.

Some users are just simply exiting out without clicking logout basically, is there a way to fire an event I guess when the session ends to capture the logout information?

Right now I just have an insert statement wired up to my login button and update statement wired up to my logout button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Global.asax.cs is an event handler

```
    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Which should get fired on session end.

Comment: Where can I find this class?

Comment: In the Global.asax.cs file of your web site. If you don't have one - go to your web site in the Solution Explorer, right click on it, choose Add, choose New Item... and add one.

Comment: it should be noted that `Session_End` does ***not*** automatically fire at the time of the user simply closing their browser - functionality that the OP was hoping to achieve.  This would not be (a complete) solution.

Comment: To catch that you'd have to use the OnBeforeUnload event of the browser (client-side script). Perhaps use it to send an Ajax request to a service to perform the update.

Comment: Problem with the OnBeforeUnload is it fires anytime you are leaving the page, not necessarily when the session is ending

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735198/is-it-possible-to-add-a-browser-code-in-javascript/3735851#3735851 (though not perfect - i think this is a pretty tough problem :P)

Comment: Agreed - it is a tough problem, you're trying to make a REST application act like an STA application and there is no really perfect way to do that.